# How to virtual-link between two different OSPF areas

Tags: cisco, routing, ospf

Is there a way to connect routers via virtual-link between two different OSPF area?

[image: topology]

Comment: What are you looking to do? What equipment are you using? What is your current setup?

Comment: I just want to link area 0 and area 6 via virtual link on ospf

Comment: What area or area's do you transit to get from 0 to 6?

Comment: @HAL: do you see the picture?

Comment: @Kveri no, sorry. I think there may be something wrong with my corporate browser settings :(

Comment: For virtual link your area must be common and one area must be with area 0

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to configure virtual link on both end point routers of the virtual link. Command in router ospf configuration is: `area <AREA_ID> virtual-link <ROUTER_ID>` where `<AREA_ID>` is transit OSPF area and `<ROUTER_ID>` is IP address (Loopback) of the other interconnecting router. Virtual links are considered to be an indicator of bad network design, so if you really need to use them maybe you should consider revising your network structure.

Comment: Virtual links can be part of a bad design; however use of the feature itself is neither good nor bad.  There are several valid use cases for virtual links.

Comment: In case of merging or aquisition, to avoid redoing the entire network and associated downtime, virtual-links could be a solution.